# Is there a way to measure ripples in water with some kind of sensor?

Tags: sensor, measurement, water

Imagine you have a water tank on the top of a truck (like firefighters have.)Is there a way to measure how much the water ripples with some sensor?

I know sensors that just tell you if there is water on them (the ones that could be used in bathroom to check for leaking water.) I could use that but I would not get much information about how much the water actually ripples. Just if the water rippled at all.

So the question is how to measure ripples in water. Situation looks like this:

[image: Situation picture]

With the help of measurements, the speed and acceleration would be controlled so that the water does not ripple too much.

Comment: so, you just need to measure water level over time (=very often). If you notice the values fluctuate, you have ripples. I think there are liquid level sensors out there, never used myself, can't recommend anything specific, but shouldn't be hard to find

Comment: Internal baffles are the way to prevent ripples being a problem. They're used in tankers. Three is a wide variety of liquid level analog sensors. Ultrasonic should be suitable for water. There are also sensors used in domestic oil tanks to send the oil level to a wireless display in the house.

Comment: I think a better English word for what you are describing would be "waves" (like on the sea or ocean) rather than "ripples" (which are very small).

Comment: I'd probably go with an ultrasonic level sensor, measured at at least 10Hz. Float sensor might work, but wouldn't be my 1st choice.

Comment: Do you just want to measure how much the water sloshes around, or prevent the water from sloshing? For measuring you could just use a camera?

Comment: A float connected to a lever connected to a potentiometer will measure the height of water at a location,

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind, but I borrowed your diagram and added the "solution".

[image]

You can build a simple water-presence sensors by having two pieces of metal near each other and measure the resistance between them - when immersed, there will be some current flow which the sensor can detect.  The red lines indicate the sensors.

You will need to lay several of them vertically on the side of your tank - preferably equidistant.  Use a microcontroller to rapidly sample them.  You can then make various estimates over time, for example, within each second, the max height minus the minimum height will give you the "ripple" you are looking for.

Comment: that's a hard to implement solution! Not only can't you read multiple sensors at the same time, because you can't tell from which electrode(s) to which electrode(s) current flows, you also need to modify the sensor surface to be very quickly self-draining and not wetting! This is not "a simple water-presence sensor", I'd say it's an exceptionally hard one to implement!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can use ultrasonic sensors to measure distance and try to get the ripple from that. It wasnt clear to me about whether you were trying to get small amounts of ripple or only large amounts (sloshing).
If you want to measure small amounts of ripple, the ultrasonic may not work well. Use capacitive measurement instead.
Here is a reference design for measuring liquid level with capacitive measurement techniques. They claim 1mm resolution.
https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu736a/tidu736a.pdf?ts=1631022049538&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F
Note that I'm assuming that this is water and not some electrolyte that may not work well for capacitive measurement.